# Measuring self-capacitance of coils

Tags: capacitance, inductance, coil

Is there a simple way of measuring the self-capacitance of a coil? There are many estimates out there for self-capacitance based on number of turns and wire specs, but I'm wondering if I can do an experiment to measure it reasonably accurately.

Answer (score 2):

You could measure the self-resonant frequency (SRF), and then calculate the capacitance from

C = \$ 1\over L \$ \$ (\$ \$ 1\over 2\cdot \pi \cdot f_R \$\$)^2\$